# Why does UICollectionView refresh data after scrolling?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

`UICollectionView` refreshes data after scrolling and changes the position of the *cells*. How can I stop it? I don't want to call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` on every scrolling?

I don't have too much data.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.logo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",news[indexPath.row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "changes the position of the cells"?

Comment: I have images inside cells. Images change on every scrolling.

Comment: Can you show your `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: can you show thw code of .h .m file of your custom cell?